# Plot data with x and y ErrorBars from file

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

If I have a set of data like this one saved in a dat file

```
 34.2       8.83      5.8     4.2         1.3362          1.3362

44.3        3.02      5.7     4.3         0.4324          0.4324

54.3        1.33      5.7     4.3         0.190427       0.190427

64.5        0.615     5.5     4.5         0.088054       0.088054 

78.1        0.273     11.9    8.1         0.03908765  0.039087651

98.6        0.0861    11.4    8.6         0.014199975 0.014199975 

122.0       0.0279    18      12          0.00548148   0.00548148

156.0       0.00954   24      16          0.002385      0.002385 

216.0           0.00116   84      36          0.00050363   0.00050363
```

The first two coliumns are the measurement values, the last 4 the errors (-dx +dx -dy +dy).

How can I plot it with the x and y error bars, with using Import[...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
data = {{34.2, 8.83, 5.8, 4.2, 1.3362, 1.3362}, {44.3, 3.02, 5.7, 4.3,
     0.4324, 0.4324}, {54.3, 1.33, 5.7, 4.3, 0.190427, 
    0.190427}, {64.5, 0.615, 5.5, 4.5, 0.088054, 0.088054}, {78.1, 
    0.273, 11.9, 8.1, 0.03908765, 0.039087651}, {98.6, 0.0861, 11.4, 
    8.6, 0.014199975, 0.014199975}, {122.0, 0.0279, 18, 12, 
    0.00548148, 0.00548148}, {156.0, 0.00954, 24, 16, 0.002385, 
    0.002385}, {216.0, 0.00116, 84, 36, 0.00050363, 0.00050363}};
ErrorListPlot[{{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[{-#3, #4}, {-#5, #6}]} & @@@ data, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help